# r data.table appears to have duplicated rows but unique doesn't find them

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table, dt, where there appear to be two copies of each row. But when I run unique(dt), there are no duplicates.

The output of `dput` on the file is below

```
structure(list(region_code.IMPACT159 = c("CHM", "CHM"), c_Crust.elas = c(1, 1), 
                       c_Mllsc.elas = c(0.437389655806453, 
                                        0.437389655806453), 
                       c_FrshD.elas = c(0.361233613522818, 
                                        0.361233613522818), 
                       c_OPelag.elas = c(0.361774165068678, 
                                         0.361774165068678
                       ), 
                       c_ODmrsl.elas = c(1, 1), 
                       c_OMarn.elas = c(-0.09, -0.09), 
                       c_FshOil.elas = c(0.382700000000001, 
                                         0.382700000000001), 
                       c_aqan.elas = c(0, 0), 
                       c_aqpl.elas = c(0, 
                                       0)), 
                  sorted = "region_code.IMPACT159", 
                  class = c("data.table", 
                            "data.frame"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
                  .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fd6af00e2e0>)
```

I can't run this directly because of the internal self ref code. But when I delete that the resulting file does show one row is duplicated. I've been running this type of code for a long time so I'm not sure what has changed to cause this. I'm using version 1.11.9 of data.table

Comment: For me `unique(dt)` returns one row based on the example

Comment: This might be related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), which is a floating-point equality issue. Unfortunately, with the data you've provided, we cannot see the "no-duplicates" phenomenon. I don't see how it could be different, but does `unique.data.frame(...)` work any differently?

Comment: It does for me too. I tried unique.data.frame and it didn't work any differently. I got down into the weeds of the code. The (unsatisfactory) explanation is that I was doing a weighted.mean that I didn't need to do. And doing it on two identical rows that had a different value in a year column. Then I removed the year column. Once I got ride of the weighted.mean code, the duplication problem went away. I'm still puzzled by the problem with the unique function, but a deadline approaches today. If someone is interested later, I could create an RDS file and see if the problem transfers into it.